# Como proceder quando não tem o motivo correto para excluir?

Tags: debate

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70078/1333) e outras duas na mesma pergunta caíram na fila de publicações de baixa qualidade e claramente deveriam ser deletadas por ser um *troll* tentando aparecer.

O problema é que não se enquadraria em nenhuma das opções (eu marquei "isso deveria ser um comentário e não uma resposta"), na minha concepção falta uma opção do tipo "isso não é uma resposta válida" ou "conteúdo inadequado", tendo em vista que isso não é um comentário, nem uma pergunta no canto errado, mas sim conteúdo **realmente** inadequado (ao ponto de eu quase enquadrar como spam).

Então como devemos proceder? Continuamos colocando como um comentário no lugar errado?

Comment: Ou não colocas nenhum comentário e aproveitas e sinalizas para os moderadores...

Comment: Quando não tem um motivo definido ou alguém já comentou na resposta explicando o motivo, eu deixo marcado o "nenhum comentário" :)